# gcloud.py attributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'Int Flag'

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

I get this error message when running install.bat (or install.sh through 'bash' shell) of google-cloud-sdk.
Python is version 3.6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the message generated by Python3, while google cloud is expecting Python2.

Answer (score 5):

You need Python 2.7 to use gcloud, as described in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#windows.

On windows you can choose to use "bundled python" option in which case gcloud will use its own version of python 2.7 without interfering with your installed version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new reason for this error after a recent upgrade to Google Cloud SDK 303.0.0; gcloud (the start script in sdk/bin) prefers python3 and detects it and uses it (on MacOS), but that error shows. Just use the following line until Google has fixed the problem:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="python2"
```

Another reason can be that the variable PYTHONPATH is set incorrectly. Try: `unset PYTHONPATH` before starting python.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure two things:

1. While installing the GoogleCloudSDK, check the 'BundledPython' option. It will install both python and python3.
2. Make sure your environment variable-PYTHONPATH is pointing to the directory having the python.exe file.

This worked out for me.